# How can I create a nested virtual directory in IIS through Octopus deploy?

Tags: powershell, iis, virtual-directory, octopus-deploy

I have a powershell script to create a virtual directory.However, I want to create a nested virtual directory in IIS through Octopus deploy using PowerShell script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you just use something like below?

```
#Create a virtual directory
New-WebVirtualDirectory -Name 'Test' -Site 'Default Web Site\Website1' -PhysicalPath 'C:\inetpub'
#Create a nested virtual directory
New-WebVirtualDirectory -Name 'Test2' -Site 'Default Web Site\Website1\Test' -PhysicalPath 'C:\inetpub'
```

Comment: This created a empty virtual directory. How should I map the nested virtual directory with some images from another folder?

Comment: Use `-PhysicalPath` argument?

Answer (score 1):

If possible you should leverage the tool and avoid writing bespoke PowerShell which will need to be maintained and import a tested template from the `Octopus Deploy Template Library`.

https://library.octopusdeploy.com/step-template/actiontemplate-iis-virtual-directory-create

Comment: Agreed, if possible use Octopus built-in templates or from the library. If need something different could alternatively utilize `Script Modules` under `Library` section. At least then you should get a single point of maintenance.